# Calculating the sum. Unintendedly getting fractions rounded. C++

Tags: c++

I need to write a code to calculate the following sum:

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int m,n;
    cin>>n>>m;
    float sum = 0.0, prod = 1.0;
    int i = 2;
    while(i <= n)
    {
        int j = 3;
        while(j <= m)
        {
            prod = prod * (float)(i*i/j);
            j++;
        }
        sum+=prod;
        i++;
    }
    cout<<sum<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, getting a wrong answer and I guess it's because `(float)(i*i/j)` this part. It's rounding the fraction. How to fix this little problem?

Comment: Use `((float)(i*I)/(float)j)`

Comment: The parenthesis around `(i*i/j)` through operator precedence, say evaluate fully what is between `(...)`. That happens before the cast `(float)(..)` is applied. Integer division will get you every time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recast `j`:

```
prod = prod * (i * i / (float)j);
```

This will promote the product to a `float`.

Some rules of conversion may be useful, generally: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions

Comment: Yeah, now it seems to be working right. Thanks. But when n=3, m=3 I'm getting 5.3333 ( think it should be 4.3333). Any other mistake in the code?

Comment: Debug the value of `prod` just before your inner loop. Is it initialized properly at the start of the inner loop, at each inner loop instance?